# Gradle - Custom task classes in a custom folder within the same project

Tags: gradle

I have a custom Gradle Task in my project under /buildSrc/src/main/groovy. Since this folder is in parallel to the main project's /src/main/groovy folder, my IDE considers /buildSrc as a sub-project.

From the documentation, I understand the custom tasks can reside either under /buildSrc or under a separate project.

I don't want to create a new project, so I am thinking of keeping it somewhere other than /buildSrc. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. The IDE likely considers `buildSrc` a subproject in order to offer IDE support for developing custom tasks and plugins (not because the directory is "parallel" to anything).